# Magento -How can i add static block to another store view

Tags: magento-1.8

Hello I am new to magento. I have installed magento theme named "galarainbow" and now i want to add Arabic store view for it, but my problem is static blocks I have recreate static blocks with same name and code and added each one to different store view, but the new store block doesn't appear how can i make it visible?

Comment: Make Sure that you After Creating Static Block you have update  the Cache.

Comment: Also make sure its assigned to the right store view